# Aptana Studio выдает ошибку при запуске руби скрипта

Tags: aptana

При запуске руби скрипта Aptana Studio выдает ошибку:[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В чем может быть дело?

Comment: очевидно студия не знает где искать руби для выполнения скрипта. Обычно такое в свойствах студии/проекта прописывается в других IDE

Comment: а не подскажите, где это? А то все уже смотрел, найти не смог.

Comment: не подскажу. аптану ставил 1 раз и очень давно и на руби уже не пишу. Обычно все лежит в подобие settings - inetrpreter